# Onclick function toggleClass() issue with two div at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I using same `onclick` function on two `span`, When clicking on `text 1 span` it is adding `active` class and when clicking again removing the class. It is working fine on both span's.
I just want if when clicked `text 1 span` so the `active` class is added to `text 1 span` and when i click on `text 2 span` add `active` class to this span but remove it from `text 1 span`.
Available on codepen https://codepen.io/hnpiocyj-the-encoder/pen/VwRZBrW

```html
<span class="selected" onclick="select(this);">text 1</span>
<span class="selected" onclick="select(this);">text 2</span>
```

```
function select(i){
    e = window.event
    $(i).toggleClass("active");
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

I want if text 1 span has active class and when i click on text 2 span add active class but also i want to remove the active class from text 1 span.

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? I see none

Comment: Where? it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get all the `active` spans in your function and remove the `active` class from them. After removing, you can make use of your `this` object, passed in the function argument, to add a new `active` class.

See the demo below:

```js
function select(currObj) {
  const allActiveSpans = document.querySelectorAll('span.active');
  allActiveSpans.forEach(span => {
    if(span !== currObj){
      span.classList.remove('active');
    }
  });
  currObj.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<span onclick="select(this);">text 1</span>
<span onclick="select(this);">text 2</span>
```

Comment: Also i want if text 2 is active when click on it also remove the active from text 2

Comment: I have updated the answer. It is working as per your requirements now.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require you simply need to remove the class from all other `.selected` elements, *except* the one which you clicked on.

Also note that there's a couple of other changes your should make to improve the quality of your code. Firstly, don't use inline `onclick` attributes. They're bad practice and have been superceded by unobtrusive event handlers which can be bound in the JS itself.

Seconly, don't use the global `window.event` object as it's not available in all browsers. If you use unobtrusive handlers, then your handler function will be provided the Event as an argument which you can use to identify the element that fired the event.

With those changes made, your code would look something like this:

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');

const toggleActiveClass = e => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  // toggle the class on the current element
  e.target.classList.toggle('active');
  
  // remove the class from all other elements
  spans.forEach(span => {
    if (span !== e.target) {
      span.classList.remove('active');
    }
  });
}

spans.forEach(span => span.addEventListener('click', toggleActiveClass));
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #C00;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<span class="selected">text 1</span>
<span class="selected">text 2</span>
```

Comment: Exactly working perfect but i want it like onlick function?

Comment: The other answers have that covered, but I would ***strongly*** suggest you do not do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can use it's function `is()` to check if the target element is equal to another element:

```js
function select(i){
   //get the clicked element as a jQuery object
   const $clicked = $(i);
   //iterate each span with the className 'selectable'
   //added className `selectable` to the spans that you want to
   //use so you don't have to select every span on the page
   $('span.selectable').each(function(i, el) {
       //use jQuery .is to see if the element is the one that was clicked
       //if not remove the class active else toggle the class
       if(!$(el).is($clicked)){
          $(el).removeClass('active');
       } else {
          $(el).toggleClass('active');
       }
   });
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #C00;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<span class="selectable" onclick="select(this);">text 1</span>
<span class="selectable" onclick="select(this);">text 2</span>
```

Comment: Also i want if text 2 is active on click unactive it?

Comment: @AmirAlam added your extra requirement. Please see update.

Answer (score 0):

Also...

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');

function select(element)
  {
  if ( element.classList.toggle('active') ) // this method return a Boolean value
    {
    spans.forEach( sp =>
      { 
      if (sp !== element)
        sp.classList.remove('active');
      })
    }
  }
```

```css
.active {
  background-color : #C00;
  color            : #FFF;
  }
```

```html
<span class="selected" onclick="select(this);">text 1</span>
<span class="selected" onclick="select(this);">text 2</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the below jQuery code to achieve this.

```js
//This is document ready function
$(function() { 

  // add a click handler for the spans that are direct children of .holder
  $(document).on("click", ".holder>span", function(){
    
    // here $(this) is the current clicked span element
    const that = $(this);
    
    // remove active class of clicked span's siblings
    that.siblings().removeClass('active');
    
    // add an active class for current element
    that.addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.holder span{
  border: 1px solid rgba(225,22,22, 0.1);
  background-color: rgba(22,220,22, 0.3);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.holder span.active{
  background-color: rgba(22,222,22, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="holder">
  <span>Text 1</span>
  <span>Text 2</span>
  <span>Text 3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the behaviour you're looking for, where clicking on one span adds the 'active' class to it and removes the 'active' class from the other, you'll need to modify your select function. Currently, your function toggles the 'active' class for the clicked element but doesn't affect the other element. Here's an updated version of the function that should work for your requirements:

```
function select(i) {
  // Prevents the event from affecting parent elements
  e = window.event
  e.stopPropagation();

  // Adds 'active' class to the clicked element
  $(i).addClass("active");

  // Removes 'active' class from all other '.selected' elements
  $('.selected').not(i).removeClass('active');
}
```